# Adobe Photoshop hardware acceleration

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When i've trying to use Face Tool in Liquify tool, i get an error: The Face Tool requires hardware acceleration. Check the Perfomance Preferences and verify that "Use Graphics Processor" is enabled.

But in Perfomance settings, all these settings are On, and GPU Compatibility chek says that "Your graphics processor is compatible"

Adobe Photoshop Version: 24.1.1 20230112.r.238 4bbfa7a x64

I've tried to update my graphics driver, so now it is latest version of nvidia driver (528.49 from 02/08/2023)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Tech support is off topic here. You should contact Adobe instead. Sorry about that.

Comment: yes its typically caused by your on integrated graphics card, disabe it (or go to windows settings and force photoshop to use your addon card, but this might not work sometimes which is a really bad thing for laptops) and you should have no problems